# Trouble with django templating looping over a dict created from an xml response

Tags: python, django, xml

I am trying to display data in the html page from an xml request. I have converted the xml content to a dict using xmltodict. The xml data is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<countriesRS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/messages">
    <from>1</from>
    <to>207</to>
    <total>207</total>
    <auditData processTime="30" timestamp="2020-10-01 18:10:02.666" requestHost="10.185.89.196" serverId="ip-10-185-88-253.eu-west-1.compute.internal.node.int-hbg-aws-eu-west-1.discovery" environment="[awseuwest1, awseuwest1a, ip_10_185_88_253]" release="cbd9f69ac1e7076b6ae86a8358f1e1bf26e00f44" internal="94d38b94f628408a9a0e41d7673d93a8"/>
    <countries>
        <country code="AD" isoCode="AD">
            <description>Andorra</description>
            <states>
                <state code="CA">
                    <name>CANILLO</name>
                </state>
                <state code="EN">
                    <name>ENCAMP</name>
                </state>
                <state code="ES">
                    <name>ESCALDES - ENGORDANY</name>
                </state>
                <state code="AN">
                    <name>ANDORRA</name>
                </state>
                <state code="AD">
                    <name>ANDORRA LA VELLA</name>
                </state>
                <state code="07">
                    <name>ANDORRA</name>
                </state>
                <state code="XX">
                    <name>NOT ASSIGNED</name>
                </state>
                <state code="OR">
                    <name>ORDINO</name>
                </state>
                <state code="SJ">
                    <name>SANT JULIA DE LORIA</name>
                </state>
                <state code="MS">
                    <name>LA MASSANA</name>
                </state>
            </states>
        </country>
        <country code="AE" isoCode="AE">
            <description>United Arab Emirates</description>
            <states>
                <state code="DU">
                    <name>UNITED ARAB EMIRATES</name>
                </state>
                <state code="FU">
                    <name>Fujairah</name>
                </state>
                <state code="AZ">
                    <name>Abu Dhabi</name>
                </state>
                <state code="AJ">
                    <name>Ajman</name>
                </state>
                <state code="07">
                    <name>UNITED ARAB EMIRATES</name>
                </state>
                <state code="XX">
                    <name>NOT ASSIGNED</name>
                </state>
                <state code="UQ">
                    <name>Umm Al Quwain</name>
                </state>
                <state code="RK">
                    <name>Ras Al Khaimah</name>
                </state>
                <state code="SH">
                    <name>Sharjah</name>
                </state>
            </states>
        </country>
```

however, when i use a for loop to display the countries with `{% for country in response.CountriesRS.countries %}`, I can only see 'country' being displayed. How can I properly loop through this dict?
This is how the variable 'response' shows up in html:

```
OrderedDict([('countriesRS', OrderedDict([('@xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'), ('@xmlns', 'http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/messages'), ('from', '1'), ('to', '203'), ('total', '207'), ('auditData', OrderedDict([('@processTime', '28'), ('@timestamp', '2020-10-01 21:09:13.151'), ('@requestHost', '10.185.89.196'), ('@serverId', 'ip-10-185-88-253.eu-west-1.compute.internal.node.int-hbg-aws-eu-west-1.discovery'), ('@environment', '[awseuwest1, awseuwest1a, ip_10_185_88_253]'), ('@release', 'cbd9f69ac1e7076b6ae86a8358f1e1bf26e00f44'), ('@internal', '23cbd9bfc8a64401824599cc99028cc0')])), ('countries', OrderedDict([('country', [OrderedDict([('@code', 'AD'), ('@isoCode', 'AD'), ('description', 'Andorra'), ('states', OrderedDict([('state', [OrderedDict([('@code', 'CA'), ('name', 'CANILLO')]), OrderedDict([('@code', 'EN'), ('name', 'ENCAMP')]), OrderedDict([('@code', 'ES'), ('name', 'ESCALDES - ENGORDANY')]), OrderedDict([('@code', 'AN'), ('name', 'ANDORRA')]), OrderedDict([('@code', 'AD'), ('name', 'ANDORRA LA VELLA')]), OrderedDict([('@code', '07'), ('name', 'ANDORRA')]), OrderedDict([('@code', 'XX'), ('name', 'NOT ASSIGNED')]), OrderedDict([('@code', 'OR'), ('name', 'ORDINO')]), OrderedDict([('@code', 'SJ'), ('name', 'SANT JULIA DE LORIA')]), OrderedDict([('@code', 'MS'), ('name', 'LA MASSANA')])])]))]), OrderedDict([('@code', 'AE'), ('@isoCode', 'AE'), ('description', 'United Arab Emirates'), ('states', OrderedDict([('state', [OrderedDict([('@code', 'DU'), ('name', 'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES')]), OrderedDict([('@code', 'FU'), ('name', 'Fujairah')]), OrderedDict([('@code', 'AZ'), ('name', 'Abu Dhabi')]), OrderedDict([('@code', 'AJ'), ('name', 'Ajman')]), OrderedDict([('@code', '07'), ('name', 'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES')])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `.country` to your chain:

```php
{% for country in response.CountriesRS.countries.country %}
  <li>{{ country.description }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. even though country is the list of countries in the xml string, when converted to dict, the term 'country' isnt repeated, hence isnt looping. using for country in response.CountriesRS.countries.country fixed the problem.